# Displaying an array element in a View - Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to output a variable like this: `<h1>{{ $unitcode }}</h1>`

I have this code making that variable:

```
        // Validation was successful.
        $inputcode = Input::get('unitcode');
        // First validation is successful. Next to check that it is a correct unit code.
        $unitcode = DB::table('unitcodes')->where('unitcode', $inputcode)->first();

       if(!$unitcode) {
           // Input code is wrong. The unit does not exist.
            return Redirect::route('get-buy')
                ->with('global', 'That unit code does not exist. Try again.');
       } else {
           // Success! Unit code exists!
            return View::make('showbooks')
                ->with('unitcode', $unitcode);
       }
```

When I run everything it gives me this: 
`ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) 
Array to string conversion (View: ..BLAH goes on to display path to view.`

How can I get it to display the variable I want that was pulled from the DB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel's DB abastraction layer a row from a database table (result of a `SELECT ... LIMIT 1` - `DB::...->first()`) is an array.
You can send any kind of variables using `View::...->with` but you need to use them properly in the template itself (`'showbooks'`).
You most probably are doing a `{{{ unitcode }}}` in the template which is actually similar to executing an `echo $unitcode`. Now if `$unitcode` is an array and `echo` requires a string then PHP automatically tries to convert it and fails (`ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) 
Array to string conversion...`).
What you need to do is use it correctly:

```
{{{ unitcode['unitcode'] }}}
```

And this will work because `$unitcode` is a key-value dictionary where each key is a column from the DB table with its associated value.